# datatable tabletools to copy two different table on the same page

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, datatables, export-to-csv, tabletools

I am using tabletools extension. In one page, I have two different datatables with same number of columns actually in both tables. I want to copy data from both tables. But tabletools copies only one table. Also I am using sRowSelect: multi and using fnContainer to pushing all the table tool options in dropdown format. Below is my current code:

//Each datatable example like below

```
$('#abc').dataTable({
"sAjaxSource": 'abc/get_data',
//"dom": 'T<"clear">lfrtip',
"deferRender": false,
"order": [
  [16, 'asc']
], ......


var Table1 = $("#abc").DataTable();
var Table2 = $("#efg").DataTable();

MyTableTools = new $.fn.dataTable.TableTools( Table1 , {
             "sSwfPath": "../swf/copy_csv_xls_pdf.swf",
             "sRowSelect": 'multi',
             "sSelectedClass": 'row_selected',
             "bHeader": 'true',
             "aButtons": [
               {
                 "sExtends": 'collection',
                 "sButtonText": 'Tools <span class="caret" />',
                 "aButtons": [
                     {
                       "sExtends": "copy",
                       "mColumns": [0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10]
                     },
                     {
                       "sExtends": "csv",
                       "mColumns": [0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10]
                     },
                     {
                       "sExtends": "xls",
                       "mColumns": [0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10]
                     },
                     {
                       "sExtends": "pdf",
                       "sPdfOrientation": "landscape",
                       "sPdfMessage": "You current simulation is as below:",
                       "mColumns": [0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10]
                     },
                     {
                       "sExtends": "print",
                       "mColumns": [0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10]
                     }
                 ]
               }]
         } );

$( MyTableTools.fnContainer() ).insertAfter('ul.lastClass');
```

In above code, if I use MyTableTools = new $.fn.dataTable.TableTools( Table1, Table2 {..., I was expecting both tables getting copied, but its not working this way. Could anyone suggest if this is even possible?

Thanks